# How to use Terraform to create a wildcard dns record in an Amazon VPC to point to a service discovery server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, routes, wildcard-subdomain, terraform

I've got an [Amazon VPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Virtual_Private_Cloud) with a bastion and service discovery router ([Consul](https://www.consul.io/)) that I'm using to route traffic from my company's intranet to the VPC.

Now I'm running jobs in the VPC ([Webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)) that need to look up newly registered services from a [docker swarm host](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-swarm).

From the VPC I want to point to the service discovery server.

I want to create this [dns wildcard entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) using [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/).

This is my first go at it - but I feel like something is missing:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "*" {
   zone_id = "${myzone.primary.zone_id}"
   name = "*.cloud.companyintranet.com"
   type = "A"
   ttl = "300"
   records = ["${aws_eip.lb.public_ip}"]
}
```

My question is: **How to use Terraform to create a wildcard dns record in an Amazon VPC to point to a service discovery server?**

Comment: What's wrong with that? Does it not work? I'm unsure about using `*` as the resource usage name as I'd imagine that might cause some issue with Terraform's splats for things created in a loop and also the name `wildcard` seems more self explanatory anyway.

Comment: The resource part `resource "aws_route53_record" "*" ` is wrong, you can't use `*` as resource name in `terraform`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` should absolutely work for wildcards, however only in the NAME field:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "wildcard_cloud_companyintranet_com" {
   zone_id = "${myzone.primary.zone_id}"
   name = "*.cloud.companyintranet.com"
   type = "A"
   ttl = "300"
   records = ["${aws_eip.lb.public_ip}"]
}
```

Just make sure you use descriptive names in the resource field, instead of the `*`